# Customizing Push notification alert sound

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I want to implement the scream feature of lookout : www.lookout.com into my app: When the user click the button "scream" on the website, it will make my iphone scream at maximum volume. Is there anyway to customize the notification sound to play at maximum volume as in the scream feature of lookout.

Comment: I did not use the lookout app as it seems I need to sign up. Are you sure your phone will still "scream" even if you mute it?

Comment: yah, if I press the lower volume button ,it will increase the volume much more.

Comment: So I doubt whether they are really customizing the push notification sound . But if they are not doing that way, the problem is when the app is inactive(the app is still in the multitasking bar but not in foreground), as far as I know, the app will not be able to do anything when the notification come unless user press the notification message so that the app can launch.